# Is this Bash code vulnerable to code injection?

Tags: linux, exploit, vulnerability, injection, bash

I'm writing a libre program named "silently" for enhancing error handling in Bash, emulating the behavior of a [jidoka](https://www.lean.org/lexicon/jidoka).

My question is if that eval would be vulnerable to code injection if the invoking program surrounds its input with doble quotes, like this:

```
silently "function" "command \"${@}\""
```

Having silently this code:

```
#! /bin/bash


mainFunction () {
    if [ "${function}" != "" ]; then
        function="${function}: "
    fi

    error=$(eval "${command}" 2>&1)

    if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "${function}${error}" >&2
        exit "${exit}"
    fi
}


setArguments () {
    if [ "${1}" == "-try" ]; then
        function="${2}"
        command="${3}"
        exit="0"
    else
        function="${1}"
        command="${2}"
        exit="1"
    fi
}


setArguments "${@}"
mainFunction "${@}"
```

Comment: Just checking: is your threat scenario that somebody who can run an arbitrary command in your shell might... inject a command into your shell? Or are you imagining an attacker who can control at least part of one parameter but not the rest of the command line?

Comment: The attacker initially could only control the content of `${@}`.

Comment: `${@}` could contain `echo \`cat /etc/paswd\`;return -1`, for sample!

Comment: It doesn't result in code execution:./test.sh "echo `cat /etc/paswd`;return -1"
cat: /etc/paswd: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/silently: line 9: echo ;return -1: command not found

Answer (score 2):

There are two quick observation:

- Using `eval` is very dangerous and your variable `${command}` is not efficiently sanitized. (They could contain backticks, period, control chars, etc)
- Using `bash` for sensible operation is not recommended as they suffer from a lot of vulnerabilities. I recommend using poor `shell` (like `dash`), for critical scripts. (Or more evolved languages like Python or Perl).
- Sample of unexpected behaviour:

  ```
  /path/to/silently Blah "'echo `date`;return 1'"
  Blah: Wed Oct 16 08:26:16 CEST 2019
  ```

  Where command between *backticks* are executed, semicolons do command separation (as usual) and `return 1` force *`mainFunction`* to consider the result as an error then print them.

  By using the code you've published @gitlab.com, result of this look like:

  ```
  /path/to/silently Blah "'echo `date`;return 1'"
  silently: surplus arguments on: Blah 'echo Thu Oct 17 13:54:36 CEST 2019;return 1'
  Note that command must be quoted
  ```

  `date` command is executed and result shown as error text.

  Then you could try:

  ```
  /path/to/silently Blah "'echo `cat /etc/passwd`;return 1'"
  ```

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to do sensible operation is something possible, but do require strong experience. I personally  recomand to not do that!

Comment: Thanks. `command` is not the variable, but a hard-coded command. The variable is `${@}`. When I put it between double quotes the terminal didn't interpret control chars as such, so I was wondering if that's the case under any circumstance.

Comment: Sample issue: `silently Blah 'echo \`date\`;return 1'`

Comment: Results in: `silently: surplus arguments on: Blah echo 'date';return 1`

Comment: By the way I have turned this code into a full application: https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/silently

Comment: Ok, I've downloaded your code then tryed: `./silently Blah "'echo \`cat /etc/passwd\`;return 1'"`. Please note double-quote enclosed quotes, enclosing backticks... I think showing password file is an *unexpected behaviour*! Note: ***eval is evil!***

Comment: As said in the question the malicious code shall be in a variable, otherwise it means it's hard-coded. Also the question and `man silently` instructs that variable to be surrounded by escaped double quotes to prevent any injection. The vulnerable sample shall follow that context.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no reason to worry about code injection on a local shell script.

If you are running this remotely it could be an issue. I did some experimenting with the example below and didn't find any direct ways to inject any extra commands, except for the one word. Keep in mind, that you should also whitelist the allowed commands in a production environment.

Example:
silently "command \"whoami\""

```
#! /bin/bash
command="${@}"
result=$(eval "${command}" 2>&1)
echo "${result}"
```

Comment: Thank you. For example `silently echo this; ls` will execute `ls`, where `silently "echo this; ls"` will not. So if we have `silently "command ${arguments}"`, arguments inside double quotes, it seems enough for the terminal to understand that arguments shall not be executed in any case. I was wondering if there could be a case where that's not true.

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella it will, because you are using eval function

Comment: I would need a sample where that happens, because I have been unable to find one.

Comment: Do this silently "function" "whoami;whoami"

Comment: That sample can only be hard-coded, not injected.

Comment: Well, you just recently updated the comments, I had misunderstood the parameter passed as to which is in attackers control. You can't inject multiple commands as well as you can't use any spaces.